# Modify the content of a field using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to get data from a sql database. There is a field called "code" in which the content has
this structure:

PO0000001209

ST0000000909

And what I would like to do is to remove the 6 zeros after the letters to get the following result:

PO1209

ST0909

I will put the result in another field called "code_short" and use it for my query in elasticsearch. I have configured the input
and the output in logstash but I am not sure how to do it using grok or maybe mutate filter

I have read some examples but I am quite new on this and I am a bit stuck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `mutate/gsub` filter for this but that will replace the value of the `code` field:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "code", "000000", "",
    ]
  }
}
```

Another option is to use a `grok` filter like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "code" => "(?<prefix>[a-zA-Z]+)000000%{INT:suffix}" }
    add_field => { "code_short" => "%{prefix}%{suffix}"}
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used the second one, it fits exactly to what I was looking for, thanks!!

Comment: I was wondering if you can help with this topic I have created and it is related to this question you helped me to resolve, any help would be great, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203738/from-a-given-field-depending-on-the-content-mofify-it-and-store-it-in-differen