# From a given field, depending on the content, mofify it and store it in different new fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have created this new topic to avoid confusion but it is related to the following topic, which was resolved:

[Modify the content of a field using logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958787/modify-the-content-of-a-field-using-logstash)

Let's say that in field called `code` the content are also words, like: `notification` or `mountain` and I would like to create another field called `code_word` to store those words.

So from the field called `code` in the database, depending on its content it would create `code_short`, and `code_word`.

I was trying something like this:

```
grok {
  match => { "code" => "(?<prefix>[a-zA-Z]+)000000%{INT:suffix} %{WORD:word}" }
  add_field => { "code_short" => "%{prefix}%{suffix}"}
  add_field => { "code_word" => "%{word}"}
}
```

but clearly is not working: _grokparsefailure.

I am not sure how to do it, I am wondering if it could be done using a conditional like an "if".

This is the output:

```
    {
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 43,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg75",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.360Z",
               "code": "molfix-oat",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg77",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.365Z",
               "code": "PO0000002221",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8C",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.372Z",
               "code": "ST0000003302",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8K",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.382Z",
               "code": "notifications-set",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8M",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.384Z",
               "code": "PO0000001111",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8N",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.385Z",
               "code": "PO0000000808",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8R",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.388Z",
               "code": "TT0000000009",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8U",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.391Z",
               "code": "ST0000001113",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8c",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.398Z",
               "code": "test/bin/UT0",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test1",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "AVo3yno0PoyZlwFEpg8g",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:05:00.400Z",
               "code": "PO0000001203",
               "@version": "1",
               "tags": []
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go about it is to detect the `grokparsefailure` tag and assign the value to `code_word` instead:

```
grok {
  match => { "code" => "(?<prefix>[a-zA-Z]+)000000%{INT:suffix}" }
  add_field => { "code_short" => "%{prefix}%{suffix}"}
}
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
   mutate {
      add_field => { "code_word" => "%{code}"}
      remove_field => ["tags"]
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.Now it is creating "code_word" with the same content as "code".It is not creating the formatted field "code_short" anymore.What I am trying to achieve is from the given field "code" generate two different fields depending on its content,"code_short" with the content like PO1209,and the other,"code_word" with only the words that field "code" has it some of its rows. Any other idea to make this work? many thanks

Comment: I need to see one sample of `code` value that would not match the grok pattern and that you need to see stored in `code_word`, then. The way I see it, if the pattern matches, you only get `code_short` and if the pattern doesn't match, you only get `code_word`

Comment: Would be like this:

Examples of samples of field "code" to be stored in "code_word", values:

molfix,

notificaion-oat,

cortex,

And examples of samples of field "code" to be stored in "code_short", values before formatting:

PO0000001209,

ST0000000909,

Once stored in "code_short" they would be like:

PO1209,

ST0909,

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it'd be easier if you can share full log lines of each type.

Comment: Well the information logstash is grabbing is coming from a database, and field "code" is one of its fields, it is not coming from a logfile if that is what you mean?

Comment: Just output the records you get using the `stdout` output (with `json` codec)  without any filters, so we can see what they look like

Comment: Yes, but don't put that in an answer, just update your question with that content.

Comment: thanks a lot!! it works great. Sorry about adding new info in an answer, noted for next time. thanks again

Comment: I am wondering if you could help with the following question related to elasticsearch, many thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413904/is-it-possible-to-use-fuzziness-for-only-one-field-in-a-multi-match-query