# Is it possible to use fuzziness for only one field in a multi_match query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following multi_match query in Elasticsearch and I am wondering if I can use fuzziness only for "friendly_name field". I have tried different things but doesn't seem to work. I am also wondering if it possible to use an analyzer to get a similar result as the fuzziness does:

```
    "query": { 
  "multi_match": {
         "query": "input query",            
         "fields": ["code_short", "code_word","friendly_name"],
         "minimum_should_match": "2"
  }   }, "_source": ["code", "friendly_name"]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need query on one field , you don't need multi match

```
"match": {
        "name": {
            "query":     "your query",
            "fuzziness": "1.5",
            "prefix_length": 0,
            "max_expansions": 100,
            "minimum_should_match": "80%"
        }
    }
```

I don't believe that you can fully replace fuzziness, but you have 2 options to explore that might work for you. ngram filter or stemmer filter.

======
Well it wasn't very clear to me what you've intended. But you can do your query that way:

```
"query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "friendly_name": {
                "query": "text",
                "fuzziness": "1.5",
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "code_word": {
                "query": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "code_short": {
                "query": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 2
      }
```

}

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am using multi_match because I am actually querying three fields and I haven't found the way to apply fuzziness to only one of them. I have tried ngram but I don't get the result I would like, I'll have a look at the stemmer filter though, thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for the information, it gives me some hints on how could I make it work